# What does the valediction "Ever yours" mean?

Tags: meaning, etymology, letter-writing, valediction

A friend of mine recently said they think it sounds romantic, but I have seen it used in platonic situations.  What does this valediction actually mean?  I would also be interested in knowing this valediction's origin, if anybody knows.

Comment: It signals that the author is ‘of a certain age’.

Comment: "I will be your [friend/lover  - whatever you are to them now] for ever."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Ever yours", "Yours ever, "Yours Always", are used less today at least in the US and usually imply some persistent affection or friendship, but not necessarily a romantic connection.

[Webster Online says](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/Yours%20ever) it's just a way to end an informal letter

A book entitled *Ever Yours: The Essential Letters* contains letters from Vincent van Gogh (1853-1890) to various people he knew.